# Programmatically set signatures in Outlook client using JAVA

Tags: java, outlook

I want to set signatures for multiple address in outlook client application. I read concepts using VBA and other scripts. But I want to do it in Java. I have already created the html signature files. I can use AD to pull user information but I don't know how to connect it with Outlook using Java. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Object Model does not expose signatures at all.

On the Outlook account level, the name of the signature is stored in the account profile data accessible through the [IOlkAccountManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960327.aspx) Extended MAPI interface. Since that interface is Extended MAPI, it can only be accessed using C++ or Delphi. You can see the interface and its data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click the `IOlkAccountManager` button.
:
[image]

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am also its author), you can use its [RDOAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm) object (accessible in any language, including Java). New message signature name is stored in the `0x0016001F` property, reply signature is in `0x0017001F` (can be read or set using `RDOAccount.Fields[]`).
You can also use the [RDOAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm).`ReplySignature` and `NewSignature` properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will look into Redemption. I want to set signatures to all my domain users. So, should I have redemption installed in all PC?

Comment: Yes, wherever the code using Redemption is running.

Comment: No, I haven't used Redemption. I don't want use any tools. Is there any other possible way to set signatures in outlook client application

Comment: IOlkAccountManager in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi)